# impossible to protect a route with react-router-dom 6

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I use the React framework and react-router-dom 6 for routing.
In my application, the base route is /. (login)
The user is prompted to log in, and if recognized by the database, they are redirected to /home.
On the other hand, if the user is unable to log in, the user remains on /login.
I would simply like to protect a route: the /home route to prevent a user from accessing this route by typing in the "/home" URL.
I don't really understand how to do this. I've searched everywhere on the internet but nothing works.
With my current code I can't reach /home, but neither can I when I'm properly homed.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import ControlPanel from './components/ControlPanel/ControlPanel';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoutes from './components/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Router>
          <Routes>

            <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
              <Route element={<ControlPanel/>} path='/cpanel' exact/>
            </Route>
            <Route element={<Login/>} path='/'></Route>
          </Routes>
      
      </Router>
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoutes = () => {

    let auth = {'token':false}
    return(
       auth.token ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/"/>
    )
}

export default PrivateRoutes
```

Concerning the Login component, I make a request with Axios and if the user is recognized then I redirect to /cpanel. Here is an excerpt of this component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import imageNice from '../../images/Nice.jpg';
import axios from 'axios';

const Login = () => {
  const [id, setid] = useState('');
  const [pass, setpass] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const [buttonLoading, setButtonLoading] = useState(false);
  const [buttonSuccess, setButtonSuccess] = useState(false);
  const navigate= useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    
      try {
        setButtonLoading(true);
    
        const response = await axios.post('https://---------------/api/connexion', {
          id,
          pass,
        });
    
        if (response.data.success) {
          setButtonSuccess(true);
          setMessage('Connection success !');
          navigate('/cpanel');;

          
        } else {
          setError('id or pass incorrect');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('error to connect', error);
        setError('error');
      } finally {
        
        setTimeout(() => {
          setButtonLoading(false);
          setButtonSuccess(false);
        }, 2000);
      }
    };
```